# How can I fade a game object in and out over a specified duration?

Tags: unity

I would like to know how I can fade a game object in and out. I would like to achieve this using a C# script. As I am quite new to Unity I've read about coroutines but still haven't fully grasped the concept. I would appreciate some assistance.

Comment: As is usually the case with questions like these, I suggest a tween engine, like [DoTween](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32416) as it is far more flexible and easy to use than doing it manually.

Comment: It is also unclear what you mean by "fade a gameobject in and out".

Comment: We can make the answers more specific if you tell us what components are on the GameObject. As noted below, different approaches work for fading meshes vs. sprites, and text, line/trail renderers, and particle systems can have their own quirks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've already configured your material in the Inspector to use transparent blending (otherwise it will ignore the mucking with alpha we're doing below), you can use a simple coroutine like this:

(If using a SpriteRenderer, you'd modify the color property of the SpriteRenderer rather than passing the material, but the rest can stay the same)

```
// Define an enumerator to perform our fading.
// Pass it the material to fade, the opacity to fade to (0 = transparent, 1 = opaque),
// and the number of seconds to fade over.
IEnumerator FadeTo(Material material, float targetOpacity, float duration) {

   // Cache the current color of the material, and its initiql opacity.
   Color color = material.color;
   float startOpacity = color.a;

   // Track how many seconds we've been fading.
   float t = 0;

   while(t < duration) {
       // Step the fade forward one frame.
       t += Time.deltaTime;
       // Turn the time into an interpolation factor between 0 and 1.
       float blend = Mathf.Clamp01(t / duration);

       // Blend to the corresponding opacity between start & target.
       color.a = Mathf.Lerp(startOpacity, targetOpacity, blend);

       // Apply the resulting color to the material.
       material.color = color;

       // Wait one frame, and repeat.
       yield return null;
   }
}
```

You can use this like so:

```
// .material getter clones the material, 
// so cache this copy in a member variable so we can dispose of it when we're done.
_myMaterial = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;

// Start a coroutine to fade the material to zero alpha over 3 seconds.
// Caching the reference to the coroutine lets us stop it mid-way if needed.
_currentFade = StartCoroutine(FadeTo(_myMaterial, 0f, 3f));
```

Comment: I would be grateful if you could check this out for me https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/149126/how-to-rotate-a-parent-object-while-rotating-a-child-object-to-a-certain-angle-u

Comment: @Bane: It's somewhat baffling to me why you would even want to do something like that. It seems like a recipe for a headache. ;) Can you edit your question to include a bit more context about what these transformations represent, and why they have to be parented rather than animated independently?

Comment: I just edited the question

Comment: After rethinking what I want to achieve I've given the question a total makeover ;)

Comment: is what I want to achieve clear and understandable enough now?

Comment: still trying to solve the issue. I haven't made much progress. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: @DMGregory I asked this question that is closely related to your answer https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/153774/how-to-fade-determine-properties-to-fade-materials-out-for-the-line-renderer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a mesh, you will need to adjust the color on the material you are using with your mesh renderer like this.

```
GetComponent<Material>().color = somevalue;
```

If you are using a sprite, you can change the color from the spriterenderer like so:

```
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = somevalue;
```

The way I would suggest making your gameobject fade in and out is with two functions, FadeIn() and FadeOut().

```
    void FadeIn()
{
    renderer.material.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, Mathf.Lerp(0, 1, FadeTime));
    if (FadeTime > 1)
    {
        FadingIn = false;
    }
}
    void FadeOut()
{
    renderer.material.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, Mathf.Lerp(1, 0, FadeTime));
    if (FadeTime > 1)
    {
        FadingOut = false;
    }
}
```

Full code here: https://hastebin.com/upeqihamin.cs

Also, you need to make sure that if you are using a mesh and the default shader, the Rendering Mode, **must** be set to Fade or Transparent

Comment: Your post isn't well formatted and I'm pretty sure this code won't work.  It would fade the object in and then on the next frame, make it invisible as you never reset `FadeTime` in between the two operations, leading to `Math.Lerp(1,0,FadeTime)` to see a third value of `1.02` and return a value of 0 instantly.  Additionally, key parts of the code necessary to make your answer complete are off-site.  At a minimum, the update function should be in your answer as well.

Comment: @Draco18s I tested it out and it works perfectly fine. Here it is in action https://streamable.com/1cman
You cannot see it but I am checking and unchecking the bools in the inspector

Comment: Ah, you are correct.  Mathf.Lerp notes that *`The parameter t is clamped to the range [0, 1].`* which I would consider "black box behavior." It makes sense, it just doesn't read intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

The code from Ariss is quite ok, but if you want to take care of how long lasts the fade transition, it would be easier to use coroutines.

Coroutines in Unity are declared like **IEnumerators**

```
IEnumerator SomeAsyncStuff ( /*whatever parameter*/ )
{
    // some code
    // coroutines must have a 'yield' statement
    // which stops its execution for X time,
    // depending on the yield statement
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();    // this stops execution until next frame
}

// StartCoroutine is the method that invokes a coroutine
void Start () { StartCoroutine ( SomeAsyncStuff () ); }
```

Also, objects must have a material that supports transparency — Standard Shader does if rendering Mode is set to "Fade" or "Transparent". But the thing is, you don't want your object to be transparent when it's not fading. Mostly because semi-transparent objects don't cast shadows.

```
// this changes Standard Shader render mode
// 0 - opaque
// 1 - cutout
// 2 - fade
// 3 - transparent
material.SetFloat ( "_Mode", 0 );
```

[Here you have](https://gist.github.com/marsh12th/b623e6cc29301771d7eb96ffa3e5c11f) complete code.

It's commented so you know what everything is there for.

Comment: Same problem as with answer above, if the link breaks (many links break in a few year), the answer text itself will not be enough, can you include at least minimal version of code in you answers? Also note that `color.a != targetTransparency` might be problematic as it might never be fulfilled due to float inaccuracy.

Comment: link shouldn't break as it redirects to a GitHub gist (which I'm not deleting) but still I see your point, I will edit to provide some actual code.

Comment: Also float inaccuracy is not a problem since Lerp function clamps t value to range [0-1]

Comment: yes, it will be correctly displayed, but also silently create infinite loop. If that happens and you call it again, you will have bunch of weird results.... and good luck finding such bug.

Comment: where's the infinite loop coming from? If you call the method before last fading ends, transparency values will twitch until both end which can easly be solved with a bool. But it will definetly not create a infinite loop to me

Comment: when you lerp one color, to the target color by t=1 (which is clamped to 1 anyways), then always color.a will be equal to targetTransparency. float is not that innacurate