# How to fade determine properties to fade materials out for the line renderer

Tags: unity

I am trying to fade consistently fade a Line Renderer by adjusting the color property of it's material. I got the code I'm using from the accepted answer to [How can I fade a game object in and out over a specified duration?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/142791/how-can-i-fade-a-game-object-in-and-out-over-a-specified-duration).
When I used the `Default-Line` material for the line renderer I got the following error:

> Assertion failed: Material doesn't have a color property '_Color'
>   UnityEngine.Material:get_color()

When I used the `Default-Diffuse` material, nothing happened.

Finally, when I used the `Sprites-Default` material it worked perfectly.

How can I make the line renderer fade out consistently based on different material?

Comment: "Finally, when I used the Sprites-Default material it worked perfectly." So, is your problem solved? Was there something about using the Sprite material that was not "consistent" in the way that you want?

Comment: @DMGregory I want the fade code to work with all materials, for example it's not working with the `Default-Diffuse`.

Comment: That won't happen. Not every material does alpha blending with the pixels behind it. Default-Diffuse is an opaque material — changing its alpha would not render it translucent.